# Jest + Ts-Jest + @emotion Can only be used in conjunction with @emotion/babel-plugin

Tags: typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library, ts-jest, emotion

I'm trying setup jest/typescript/emotion for react component library.
Coming across the following error

```
 Component selectors can only be used in conjunction with @emotion/babel-plugin, the swc Emotion plugin, or another Emotion-aware compiler transform.
```

I've got this to work with storybook using the @emotion/babel-plugin, but little luck trying to setup jest.

My current versions:

```
   "@emotion/babel-plugin": "^11.10.2",
    "@emotion/jest": "^11.10.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
```

```
import type { Config } from '@jest/types';

const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
  verbose: true,
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  collectCoverage: false,
  // setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./scripts/setupTests.ts'],
  maxWorkers: '50%',
  watchAll: false,
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': [
      'ts-jest',
      {
        babelConfig: {
          comments: false,
          plugins: ['@emotion/babel-plugin'],
        },
        // babelConfig: true,
        // babelConfig: '.babelrc',
        // tsconfig: 'tsconfig.json',
        // ts-jest configuration goes here
      },
    ],
  },
  snapshotSerializers: [
    '@emotion/jest/serializer' /* if needed other snapshotSerializers should go here */,
  ],
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: ['packages/.*/dist'],
};

export default config;
```

Plus my tsconfig.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": ["esnext"],
    "module": "ES2015",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react"
  },
  "typeAcquisition": {
    "include": ["jest"]
  },
}
```

I'm using styled for creating the component like this

```
export const Checkbox = styled.label<{ disabled?: boolean; checked?: boolean }>`
 
    ${StyledLabel} {
      color: ${({ theme, disabled }) => !disabled && theme.text.primaryDark};
    }
```

Any insight hints for this would be grateful.

Comment: side note: i've spent two days on this without success... i've replaced with styled components. I've read somewhere problem has to do with ts-jest compilation here. https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/687#issuecomment-424958310 so i guess there shouldn't be a turn around for now. Will keep this here for future people who might come across same problem as me, or if someone found a solution for this.